# Web view don't load web image

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have loaded a webpage to a android webview which loads an image from its url to a webpage via javascript and it gives an error the page is not loading can anyone help?

`[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Image from origin 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.", source: file:///android_asset/demo3.html  (0)`

my Java code is:

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) vw.findViewById(R.id.help_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo3.html");
```

And XML is just simple web view

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/help_webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</WebView>
```

Comment: Show your efforts. share your code what you have done so far.

Comment: Hey Andy thanks for response. Reason to not post of the code previously is its very simple webview. but I have added the code any way as you asked. any suggetions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, javascript code running in a website cannot access resources from other websites. But a javascript from a website should be able to access resources from that same website. This is called [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), and is implemented by all major browsers.

Same thing also applies to android native webview [same-origin-policy-and-android-webview](https://koz.io/same-origin-policy-and-android-webview/)

You can try below methods, if your file is in your local

```
WebView wv = (WebView) vw.findViewById(R.id.help_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true).
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true)   
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true).
```

These methods exist in API 16 and later and are false by default, but it’s probably a good idea to make sure of the defaults.

Comment: I have tried those lines but they didnt solved the problem. anyway thanks for answer Punit

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same error. Javascript would try to load the image, I would get the error above. After changing the method which setups the Webview settings to the code below it started to work:

```
private void setupSettings() {
    WebSettings settings = memoryGameView.getSettings(); // memoryGameView is an instance of android.webkit.WebView
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```