# How to change WebView settings from QML

Tags: qt, webview, qml

I'm using a simple `WebView` in my QML file.

```
WebView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "file:///android_asset/example.html"
}
```

The problem is, that I'm getting an error about `access-control-allow-origin` is `null`. I found a fix for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224717/web-view-dont-load-web-image), which is using WebView `settings` property. It seems to be accessible from c++, but I haven't found any way of using this property from qml. So how can I use `WebView` settings from QML to get rid of the error? I'm using Qt 5.10.

Comment: How to configure from C ++?

Answer (score -1):

Use Qt's resource system, add the file to it, and load the file via

`url: "qrc:///android_assets/example.html"`